# Parsing R user input into plotting functions

Tags: r, input

I've been dealing with user input for various graphs. My main aim was to ask the user for an input and then parse this to a plotting function. I managed to do this for scatterplot, but not boxplot and barplot. **This is my working example:**

```
n<- function(){
    readline(prompt="enter x value to plot: ")
}

m<- function(){
    readline(prompt="enter y value to plot: ")
}

plotfun <- function(dat) {
    colx <- n()
    coly <- m()
    plot(dat[,colx], dat[,coly], main="Scatterplot", pch=20,xlab=[,colx] )      
}
```

**But when I try something similar with boxplot for example:**

```
plot2<-function(infile){
    a<-readline(prompt="which variable")
    barplot(table(infile$a))
}
```

**or**

```
a<-readline(prompt="enter...")
Boxplot( ~ a, data=infile, id.method="y")
```

**It doesn't work**

Errors were something like: can't find the object, argument "infile" is missing, with no default.

Comment: Where does the `Boxplot` function come from?

Comment: @MrFlick car::Boxplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "$" with character variable names. You must do the subsetting with `[` as you did in the other cases

```
plot2<-function(infile){
    a<-readline(prompt="which variable")
    barplot(table(infile[,a]))
}
```

If your `Boxplot` function is the one from `car`, then

```
a<-readline(prompt="enter...")
Boxplot(infile[,a], labels=rownames(infile), id.method="y")
```

Is the variable friendly equivalent. You can't use character variables in formulas either. They are taken as literal values.

Comment: Darn, i knew something was wrong.There is one more thing, when I try this while having my dataset imported in R as infile, it says there is infile missing? how is this possible?  I am doing my work in Rcmdr, is this important? edit: It works perfectly now. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: @user3523464 It's unclear from your description what the error might me. Is it the variable `infile` is missing or is the problem when you are trying to read the data that it's not there? Make sure you have the right path. But if you have a new problem, it's best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What is `infile`?

```
plot2 <- function(){
  a <- readline(prompt = "which variable")
  barplot(table(a))
}
```

Comment: infile is for example a CSV file in which there is the variable I would want to plot

Comment: I've tried this script you provided and it doesn't work, it plots something, but it is of no use. (everything colored in barplot, just a line in Boxplot.